# mysqlimport -- stack smashing detected and segmentation fault

Tags: mysql, mariadb, import

We are importing a large batch of records with `mysqlimport` tool.

We have ~800 files prepared for importing all in one directory with names such as:
`mytable.2019-10-31_17-37-1501`
`mytable.2019-10-31_17-41-1242`
`mytable.2019-10-31_17-55-1501`
`mytable.2019-10-31_19-11-2553`

This table is fairly large. With 512 columns I am concerned that there is a problem with our dynamic row sizes maybe

The command we are using:

`mysqlimport -r -f -u myUser -p'myActualPass' --fields-terminated-by='^^' --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='' --fields-escaped-by='\' --columns="id,col,col,..." DatabaseName /srv/import/*`

Error is as follows:

```
MyDatabase.myTable: Records: 1999  Deleted: 1999  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
*** stack smashing detected ***: mysqlimport terminated
./import.sh: line 8: 19651 Segmentation fault
```

**Version Info**

> MariaDB-client    x86_64    10.3.18-1.el7.centos
>
> Server version: 10.3.18-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Comment: Looks system is not health, can you check dmesg, or try to reboot(if possible) and try again.

Comment: @asktyagi thanks but that did not seem to do anything. strange since running `load data infile` with the same arguments works fine

Comment: check if mysql-client reinstallation work, also add more details like type of destination(local, SD, etc) you are putting backup and server client version.